# Running clustering analysis on a cluster causes one of the nodes to crash

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I am a user of a Rocks 4.3 cluster with 22 nodes. I am using it to run a clustering function - parPvclust - on a dataset of 2 million rows and 100 columns (it clusters the sample names in the columns). To run parPvclust, I am using a C-shell script in which I've embedded some R code. Using the R code as it is below with a dataset of2 million rows and 100 columns, I always crash one of the nodes.

```
library("Rmpi")
library("pvclust")
library("snow")

cl <- makeCluster()
load("dataset.RData") # dataset.m: 2 million rows x 100 columns
# subset.m <- dataset.m[1:200000,] # 200 000 rows x 100 columns
output <- parPvclust(cl, dataset.m, method.dist="correlation", method.hclust="ward",nboot=500)
save(output,"clust.RData")
```

I know that the C-shell script code works, and I know that the R-code actually works with a smaller dataset because if I use a subset of the dataset (commented out above), the code runs fine and I get an output. Likewise, if I use the non-parallelized version (i.e. just pvclust), that also works fine, although running the non-parallelized version defeats the gain in speed of running it in parallel.

The parPvclust function requires the Rmpi and snow R packages (for parallelization) and the [pvclust](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~shimo/prog/pvclust/) package.

The following can produce a reasonable approximation of the dataset I'm using:

```
 dataset <- matrix(unlist(lapply(rnorm(n=2000,0,1),rep,sample.int(1000,1))),ncol=100,nrow=2000000)
```

Are there any ideas as to why I always crash a node with the larger dataset and not the smaller one?

Comment: What is the _exact_ error that is reported when the node crashes.

Comment: Sys admin tells me it's crashed. However, `qstat -f` shows me an "-NA-" in the "load_avg" column and "au" in the "state" column